# Mysql delete records older than 7days while leaving lasr 1 record for each device_id

Tags: php, sql, datetime, mariadb

i have a table with device_id and date time with speed as shown below

```
 id | device_id |      server_time    | speed
 ---+-----------+---------------------+-------
 1  |     3     | 2019-06-24 13:35:37 |   25
 2  |     2     | 2019-06-22 13:35:37 |   35
 3  |     2     | 2019-06-27 15:15:22 |   23
 4  |     3     | 2019-06-24 13:35:37 |   54
 5  |     1     | 2019-06-20 13:35:37 |   55
 6  |     4     | 2019-06-10 13:35:37 |   34
 7  |     3     | 2019-06-24 13:35:37 |   4
 8  |     1     | 2019-06-21 13:35:37 |   25
```

i want to delete records older than 7 days but i need to keep at least 1 record for each `device_id` even its older than 7days.

How can I achieve that with mysql?

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant if you are asking for a mysql solution?

Comment: How do you determine which `device_id` should be kept?

Comment: mysql version: 10.1.40

Comment: need aleast 1 record for every device_id

Comment: Yes, but which one..?

Comment: there should be atleast 1 record for each device_id even its older than 7 days.

Comment: there is no mysql version 10.1.40 You are using mariadb instead.

Comment: Sorry: Server version: 10.1.40-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Again, *which one* of the `device_id` should be kept? The first one appearing? The last one? A random one? How do you decide?

Comment: lastest one ( higher id)

Comment: @Qirel, OP states at least one row should be kept for every device.

Comment: Yes, @Serg - but my question was which one of the rows should be kept - one per `device_id`, sure - but how do you determine which one? And at last, I got the answer: the highest ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a query to get the highest ID as that was the request from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929280/mysql-delete-records-older-than-7days-while-leaving-lasr-1-record-for-each-devic#comment100399895_56929280), and delete all rows where the time is older than 7 days, and not the highest ID for each group.

Since MySQL can't use a subquery on its own table in update/delete queries, you can use a sub-subquery to fetch all the highest IDs grouped by the `device_id`.

Replace `foo` with your actual table-name.

```sql
DELETE FROM foo
WHERE server_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
  AND id NOT IN(SELECT * 
                FROM (SELECT MAX(id) 
                      FROM foo 
                      GROUP BY device_id
                ) AS t)
```

- Live fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6fb4c/1

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
delete from 
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by device_id order by server_time desc) as rn
  from tablename where server_Time>=NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
)A where rn<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as `join`:

```
delete t
    from <table> t join
         (select device_id,
                 max(server_time) as max_server_time,
                 max(id) as max_id
          from <table> t2
          group by device_id
         ) t2
         on t.device_id = t2.device_id
    where t.id < t2.max_id and
          t.server_time < t2.max_server_time - interval 7 day;
```